# Delegate and AddClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, addclass

I am having a problem with getting this piece of code to work. Its built to allow for a user to click on one row to "select" it by highlighting via a different class. If another row is clicked, that one is highlighted and the current one is cleared. If one that is already highlighted is clicked again, it will be cleared back to normal.

This is within an ajax call to refresh the page, so everytime the call finishes and inserts the html for the table, this function below is then called. For some reason, every other reload of the table, this works. Ive tracked down the the line that is not functioning to be $(this).addClass(selectedUserClass) at the end of the function. The debug console log I put in there works, with the right class, but the next section does not add the class for some reason.

In firebug, the line changes from .. to , but it doesn't change? I've been looking at this for hours and I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help!

```
function loadUserListener(style) {
    if (style == "normal") {
        selectedUserClass = 'selectedUser';
        selectedJQueryClass = '.selectedUser';
    } else {
        selectedUserClass = 'selectedUserInverted';
        selectedJQueryClass = '.selectedUserInverted';
    }
    console.log('setting');
    $("#selectuser").delegate("tr", "click", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass(selectedUserClass)) {
            $(selectedJQueryClass).removeClass(selectedUserClass);
        } else if ($(selectedJQueryClass)[0]) {
            console.log('another');
            $(selectedJQueryClass).removeClass(selectedUserClass);
            $(this).addClass(selectedUserClass);
        } else {
            console.log(selectedUserClass);
            $(this).addClass(selectedUserClass);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That code does somewhat imply that you're inserting multiple elements with the ID `#selectuser`, and also setting the same delegated event handler multiple times. Change the ID to a class, and move the delegated event handler outside the ajax function.

Comment: to be clear, every time the ajax is called, it replaces the old table body with the new table body, so there are not multiple things with the same id, nevertheless I changed it to a class, but it doesn't work. And I moved the event handler outside, but it still does not work.

Comment: The issue is definitively that you're calling that function on every ajax call, and that's why it works every other time as the adding and removing of classes cancels out everytime the the exact same event handler is added an even number of times. Now you only have to figure out how to fix it, and looking at the **delegated** version of `on()` would be a good start.

Comment: how is that possible even though the table body html is completely replaced by a partial view in mvc everytime? Is there still stuff saved that I don't know about?  Also, what do you mean look at the delegated version of on?

Comment: jQuery's `delegate()` has been deprecated, and is replaced by [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It doesn't matter if you replace everything, the event handler is still there, and you keep adding the same event handler multiple times.

Comment: From the code you've posted, I can't really tell how you'd solve this. Either stop using a delegated event handler and create a non delegated event handler for the new element every time, or use a proper delegated event handler that is only called once on pageload.

Comment: Oh I figured it out, I used the jquery function "off" to remove all event handlers delegated to that table before calling the function again. Thanks for the help! If you want to post your initial response as an answer I'd love to mark it as answered! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can post the solution you used and accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

adeneo pointed out some things for me, mainly that the listener is still there even though the table is refreshed, so after every ajax call, a listener is being put on another which results in the functionality that only works on 'even' calls.

I used the 'off' function from jquery to clear the event handler every time this listener loading function is called. I also switched delegate to on to be more correct.

I essentially did this:

```
$('.selectuser').off("click");
```